# Items inside 2D array change unexpectedly

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
    int[] reusable = new int[8];
    int[] data = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int[][] bytes = new int[data.length/8][];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length/8; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 8; i2++) {
            reusable[i2] = data[i*8 + i2];
        }
        bytes[i] = reusable;
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reusable));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(bytes));
    }
```

This is the bit of code that I'm using. You can run it [here](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/DLDDQFYILU).

When we run it, we can see that all of the arrays inside of the 2D array `bytes[][]` change to match the array `reusable[]`, even though we only set `bytes[i]` to equal `reusable[]`.

**Why do all of the arrays in `bytes[][]` equal `reusable[]` instead of just `bytes[i]` equaling `reusable[]`?**

Comment: Do this experiment: after the loop finishes change an element of `bytes` and print it out again.

Comment: Also, why are you initializing bytes this way rather than using `data` directly or directly initializing `bytes` with the hard-coded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not allocating a new `reusable` array.  Actually, the name you have chosen betrays the fact that you *think* of it as reusable, but in fact it is not.

This statement: `bytes[i] = reusable;` does not magically make a new copy of the `reusable` array.  It just stores a reference to the existing array at `bytes[i]`.  Then you proceed to alter the same `reusable` array, and store the exact same reference at `bytes[i]`.  So, you are filling `bytes[]` with references to the one and only `reusable` array that you have.

So, right before your inner `for` loop, do `int[] reusable = new int[8];`

At which point you might as well admit that it is not reusable, and give it a better name, like `temp`.

Comment: If they want to keep the name the could do `bytes[i] = reusable.clone();` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bytes[i] = reusable;
```

This assigns `bytes[i]` to **refer to the same array** as `reusable`. So when you loop through and change the values of `reusable`, the changes are reflected in each row of `bytes`. You should create a new `reusable` array each time in your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length/8; i++) {
    int[] reusable = new int[8];
    // ...
}
```